# Android Custom Adapter Hangs Until I Scroll Down

Tags: java, android, debugging, mobile

I'm trying to populate a List View with Android, and I'm very new at this... Haven't seen an exact solution to the issue on here yet.  The problem appears to be in my getView(...) method in my custom adapter.  When I run the app, it instantly crashes.  When I debug, the list get populated just fine, until it reaches the bottom of the view - then it hangs until I physically scroll down, and populates again until it reaches the bottom... the process is repeated until fully populated.  Even though this issue seems to have been resolved here, none of the solutions work in this case.  Any Android guru's out there have any advice?

Here's the for the ListView xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.heytow.challenge.heycontacts.ContactsActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:id="@+id/customListView"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
</ListView>
```

and the item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="Property Image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Street Address"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact_company"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Custom Adapter:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
    private final String TAG = ContactAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Contact> mContactList;


    //constructor, call on creation
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Contact> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mContactList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mContactList.size();
    }


    //called when rendering the list
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //get the property we are displaying
        Contact contact = mContactList.get(position);

        //get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
        LayoutInflater inflater;
         View view = convertView;
        if(view == null) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            if (contact.isFavorite() == true) {
                inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_contact_layout, null);
            } else {
                inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, null);
            }
        }
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        TextView company = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_company);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);

        //set address and description
        if(contact.getName() != null) {
            name.setText(contact.getName());
        }

        if(contact.getCompanyName() != null) {
            company.setText(contact.getCompanyName());
        }


        //get the image associated with this contact
        ImageParser parser = new ImageParser();
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> urlImage = parser.execute(contact.getSmallImageURL());
        try {
            image.setImageBitmap(urlImage.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error accessing image URL: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error accessing image URL: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return view;

    }
}
```

And the call in my MainActivity class, onCreate.

```
ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ContactAdapter(ContactsActivity.this, 0, mContacts);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm simply trying to populate the ListView from an arrayList. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

*** EDIT ***

Here's the new getView - same effect - it hangs... when the data is not in view, it says "application is running" and getView does not continue until I scroll:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //get the property we are displaying
    Contact contact = mContactList.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    //get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    if(convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        if (contact.isFavorite() == true) {
            inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_contact_layout, parent, false);
        } else {
            inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, parent, false);
        }
        viewHolder.contactName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        viewHolder.contactCompany = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_company);
        viewHolder.contactImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    //set address and description
    if(contact.getName() != null) {
        viewHolder.contactName.setText(contact.getName());
    }

    if(contact.getCompanyName() != null) {
        viewHolder.contactCompany.setText(contact.getCompanyName());
    }


    //get the image associated with this contact
    ImageParser parser = new ImageParser();
    AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> urlImage = parser.execute(contact.getSmallImageURL());
    try {
        viewHolder.contactImage.setImageBitmap(urlImage.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error accessing image URL: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error accessing image URL: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: It will be easier to help if you add the stack trace of crash from the logcat.

Comment: Hi Nabin - thanks for the reply, but I'm not getting a stack trace when I debug, and the logcat just says "Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger"... I'm not sure where to find any other helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

ListView reuses the views. It appears you are inflating two different layouts for the views. Try using the same layout by merging both and set visibility for only necessary parts.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance, but that was not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I suggest you to following: a) Move all these view declaration within
>   a static class(your viewholder):

```
static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView name;
        public TextView company;
        public ImageView image;
}
```

> b) Assign your ViewHolder's views within below block:(For
>   reusability)

```
  View view= convertView;
  if(view == null) {

        if (contact.isFavorite() == true) {
            inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_contact_layout, null);
        } else {
            inflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_layout, null);
        }

        ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
        holder.company = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_company);
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    //below do the proper assignments:

    //set address and description
    if(contact.getName() != null) {
        holder.name.setText(contact.getName());
    }

    if(contact.getCompanyName() != null) {
        holder.company.setText(contact.getCompanyName());
    }
```

//Set imageview with picasso:

> 1)First add dependency on your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

> 2)Set imageviews with picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(contact.getSmallImageURL()).into(holder.image);
```

Comment: Hi Scott - I tried this solution several times, but it does not work.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Might be a problem with your asynctask code.  Try using picasso to set your imageviews, you already got the url.  See if that works.  I will edit my answer to show you.

Comment: This does appear to help a little... The problem remains, but it does not hang as much... For some reason the first value that is off screen causes the freeze - no crash... it just says "application is running" in the debugger.  If I just run, the app opens then immediately shuts down.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Use breakpoints, set breakpoints in your adapter's getView() block and use step in, step over and step out accordingly.